# Recursion function to return the path of the differences during a deep comparison

Tags: javascript

I have the below recursion function:

```
const getDiff = (object, base) => {
  const changes = (object, base, path = "") => {
    return _.transform(object, function(result, value, key) {
      if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) {
        if (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])) {
          if (!path) {
            path += `${key}`;
          } else {
            path += `.${key}`;
          }

          result[key] = changes(value, base[key], path);
        } else {
          if (!path) {
            path = key;
          }
          result[key] = { value, path };
        }
      }
    });
  };
  return changes(object, base);
};
```

I'm trying to make sure that it returns not just the properties that are different, but also the direct path of that property.

For instance, if I have,

```
const objA = {
  filter: {
    tag: 1
  },
  name: 'a'
}

const objB = { name: 'b' };
```

Then getting the diff should yield:

```
{
  filter: {
    value: { tag: 1 },
    path: 'filter.tag'
  },
  name: {
    value: 'a',
    path: 'name'
  }
}
```

But right now it returns `path: 'filter'` always. What am I doing wrong?

---

Below link for quick access to lodash for the console:

```
fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => eval(text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current path is scoped outside of `_.transform` thus it will apply to all branches.

Scope it within the result of `_.transform` and everything is ok.

E.g.:

```
const getDiff = (object, base) => {
                                //changed
  const changes = (object, base, _path = "") => {
    return _.transform(object, function(result, value, key) {
      // changed
      let path = _path;
      if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) {
        if (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])) {
          if (!path) {
            path += `${key}`;
          } else {
            path += `.${key}`;
          }

          result[key] = changes(value, base[key], path);
        } else {
          if (!path) {
            path = key;
          } else { // changed
            path += `.${key}`;  
          }
          result[key] = { value, path };
        }
      }
    });
  };
  return changes(object, base);
};
```